# How to create BigQuery view that preserves nested RECORD field

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

I have a BigQuery table with this schema:

```
|- actorEmail: string (required)                         
|- actorCallerType: string (required)                                                    
+- baseOUs: record (repeated)                                                            
|  |- baseOU: string                                                                     
|- time: timestamp (required)                                                            
|- uniquequalifier: integer (required)                                                   
|- ipAddress: string (required)                                                          
|- EventType: string (required)                                                          
|- EventName: string (required)                                                          
+- parameter: record (repeated)                                                          
|  |- name: string                                                                       
|  |- value: string
```

I want to create a view with this query:

```
SELECT actorEmail,actorCallerType,time,uniquequalifier,ipAddress,EventType,EventName,parameter
FROM <table>
WHERE baseOUs CONTAINS "/US"
```

Which doesn't work because you can't query multiple records (although there is a workaround).  With the workaround though, it flattens the parameter field which I don't want to happen.

The general idea is that the view should contain all fields except the repeated field 'baseOUs', only show records with "/US" in baseOUs, and that it **does not flatten** the parameter field.  With such a view, I can apply an ACL to the new view and grant access to the data for only people in the US, and so on for each country that has data in this table.

According to [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19458338/bigquery-how-to-preserve-nested-data-in-derived-tables) this is possible via API by making use of the flattenResults=false property.  However, I want to do this as a view in the UI, not via API.

Also came across [this article](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/data#nested) which describes how to query within repeated fields, but doesn't show how to present them in a non-flattened nature as a view.  Is what I'm trying to do even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure to enable [standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/) when creating the view, and you will need to use standard SQL when querying it as well. You can define the view as:

```
SELECT
  actorEmail,
  actorCallerType,
  time,
  uniquequalifier,
  ipAddress,
  EventType,
  EventName,
  parameter
FROM `your-project.your_dataset.your_table`
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM UNNEST(baseOUs)
  WHERE baseOU LIKE '%/US%'
);
```

This will preserve the original structure of the table, while including only the rows where one of the entries in `baseOUs` contains `/US`. You can read about more differences between legacy and standard SQL in the [migration guide](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/migrating-from-legacy-sql).

Comment: Thank you for the quick response.  Unfortunately it is not working:
Error: Table name cannot be resolved: dataset name is missing.  I think it is referring to the sub-query?

Comment: Make sure to use a table name of the form `your-project.your_dataset.your_table`, where the name is enclosed in backticks.

Comment: I unchecked "Use Legacy SQL", then removed the [] and project name so it was only dataset.tablename and that did it.  Thank you so much!!

Comment: I thought it was, but when I tried to save the view it game me this error: Failed to save view. Bad table reference "gsuiteactivities.admin_events_with_ous_as_records"; table references in standard SQL views require explicit project IDs Dismiss.  It seems I can't run the query with the project ID, and I can't save the view without the project ID.

Comment: You should be able to include the project name as part of the table reference. See my updated answer for an example.

Answer (score 1):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT * EXCEPT(baseOUs)
FROM <table>
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM UNNEST(baseOUs)
  WHERE baseOU LIKE '%/US%'
)
```